# How to fix the NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

When I run my simple Java browser, I try and visit a webpage such as http://google.com and it returns the NullPointerException error from my try catch code, how would I fix this?

Frame Class:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

public EditorPane pane;
public URLBar urlbar;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Frame frame = new Frame();

}

public Frame() throws Exception {
    super("Java Browser v1.0");

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    URLBar addressBar = new URLBar("Enter URL here!", pane);
    EditorPane contentDisplay = new EditorPane(urlbar);

    mainPanel.add(contentDisplay, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(addressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(mainPanel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700, 400);
    add(new JScrollPane(mainPanel));
    setVisible(true);
}

}
```

URLBar Class:

```
public class URLBar extends JTextField {

public EditorPane pane;

public URLBar(String text, EditorPane pane) {

    super(text);

     addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                loadContent(event.getActionCommand());
            }
        }
     );
}

public void loadContent(String userInput) {
    try
    {
        pane.setPage(userInput);
        setText(userInput);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("A wild exception appeared! Type: " + e);
    }
}

}
```

EditorPane Class:

```
public class EditorPane extends JEditorPane {

public URLBar urlbar;

public EditorPane(URLBar urlbar) {

    setEditable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    addHyperlinkListener(
            new HyperlinkListener() {
                public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event) {
                        if(event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                        urlbar.loadContent(event.getURL().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
    );

}

}
```

Comment: What is the full error message including stack trace?

Comment: If you've done even a little searching on solving a NullPointerException (NPE), you'll know that the most important bit of information that we need is the exception's associated stacktrace and some identification of the line that causes it, something that the stacktrace will tell you, and unfortunately neither of which you've posted here with your question. Please fix this so that we can help you.

Comment: Most importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Here is the stack trace:

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at URLBar.loadContent(URLBar.java:29)
 at URLBar$1.actionPerformed(URLBar.java:20)

Comment: Line 29 is pane.setPage(userInput);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to init the `pane` member in your `URLBar` constructor, which means it is null when you call `loadContent`.

Here's a fix:

```
public URLBar(String text, EditorPane pane) {

    super(text);

    this.pane = pane; // add this
     addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                loadContent(event.getActionCommand());
            }
        }
     );
}
```

Comment: No good, still gives me a NullPointerException!

Comment: @WilliamRose Again, we need to see the full error.

Comment: I get this: A wild exception appeared! Type: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Stack trace: java.lang.NullPointerException at URLBar.loadContent(URLBar.java:29) at URLBar$1.actionPerformed(URLBar.java:20)

Comment: Line 29 is pane.setPage(userInput);